# Power BI embed code throws 403 forbidden error from server

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

The embedded power BI dashboard is rendered fine at localhost domain, but on another domain it renders some time and not always, which is on server throws a error.

[errorlog image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwoC5.jpg) and [errorlog image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7xnn.jpg)

I am calling the powerbi rest api's from my server[PHP laravel] end and i am returning the embedtoken,reportid,embedurl to the client side[Angular4]. I use angular2-powerbi npm package for embedding the report on ui.
Please, some one help me on this. It's been a long time i am trying to fix this.

Early solution is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Based on "errorlog image2", your token has expired.
Here is a example how to get a new token: https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Refresh-token-using-JavaScript-SDK-example